# Writing data into NFC tag in android tutorial

Tags: android, nfc

I want to develop an android NFC based application in which I want to read and write data into NFC tags. How to do this? Can anybody tell me the tutorials and android API's.

Comment: Please, do some research yourself first, e.g. on SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start with the documentation:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html

Comment: link is dead! Thats why we noramlly post the important things here as well

Answer (score 13):

Here are two blogs posts which walk through code and have supporting videos to help developers get started reading and writing NFC tags in Android.

NFC Workshop Series: [Writing](http://tapintonfc.blogspot.com/2012/07/the-above-footage-from-our-nfc-workshop.html) To An NFC Tag:

NFC Workshop Series: [Reading](http://tapintonfc.blogspot.com/2012/07/nfc-workshop-series-how-to-read-nfc-tag.html) An NFC Tag:

Answer (score 2):

These should help you to begin the query:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NFCDemo/index.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/package-summary.html

Comment: thanks for ur answer. is there any API's to write data into NFC tag. I am not getting this one.

Comment: The NFCDemo is a dead link.

Answer (score 1):

You might find this [plugin](http://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/) (shameless plug) a good starting point, it also comes with an Android project boilderplate for reading and writing tags.